# Unregister self contained Windows Docker agent from Azure DevOps on scale

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-devops

I have an *Azure DevOps* agent in *Windows Docker Image*, and I'm running it as a *Swarm Service*, replicated, to be a pool in *Azure DevOps*.

I even using the [`--once`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops-2019#run-once) option, to terminate the container after one job (and *Swarm* will create a new instance for this image).

The only problem left is that if I **scaling down** the Swarm service (means that I terminating some running agents), they stay registered in the pool, but in *offline mode*, and after some time, it comes to be junky.

**What can I do to unregister the agent when the container is terminating?**

---

**Dockerfile**

```
.
.
.
WORKDIR c:/setup
ADD https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.170.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.170.1.zip .

COPY InstallAgent.ps1 .
COPY ConfigureAgent.ps1 .

# Reset the shell.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN powershell -noexit "& "".\InstallAgent.ps1"""

# Configure agent on startup 
CMD powershell .\ConfigureAgent.ps1
```

**InstallAgent.ps1**

```
Write-Verbose -Verbose "Extracting build agent"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem ; 
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("vsts-agent-win-x64-2.170.1.zip", "$PWD")
```

**ConfigureAgent.ps1**

```
$url = $env:TFS_URL
$username = $env:TFS_USERNAME
$password = $env:TFS_PASSWORD
$pool = $env:TFS_POOL_NAME
$agentName = "$(if (Test-Path Env:TFS_AGENT_NAME) { ${Env:TFS_AGENT_NAME} } else { ${Env:computername} })"

try
{
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Configuring agent $agentName for pool $pool"
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "url: $url"


    .\config.cmd --unattended `
                --url $url  `
                --auth Negotiate `
                --userName $username  `
                --password $password  `
                --pool $pool  `
                --agent $agentName  `
                --acceptteeeula `
                --replace `
                --gituseschannel
    
    Write-Host "Running Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

    .\run.cmd --once
}
finally
{
  Write-Host "Cleanup. Removing Azure Pipelines agent..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

  .\config.cmd remove --unattended `
                --auth Negotiate `
                --userName $username  `
                --password $password
}
```

Influenced by [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops-2019#create-and-build-the-dockerfile)